# how do i hide data in indexDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

so i'm fairly new to all this but recently started getting more into backend stuff. ive managed to make a decent recipe website using indexDB and was pretty perfect. but now im making a login system and i just want to know if anyone has any ideas on how i can hide the passwords ?
I have tried bcrypt but it has about 91 vulnerabilities when I try to install the npm package.

MongoDB i am currently learning but i have issues with connecting the database to the site.

like above i've tried bcyrpt

Comment: Here is an article on how to store passwords: https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ continue with the latest version of bcrypt

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.